# bash: app.py: command not found in heroku

Tags: python, heroku

```
PS D:\Py\PyDiscord\coronabot\covid19krbot> heroku run python3 app.py
Running python3 app.py on ⬢ covid19krbot... up, run.7553 (Free)
bash: app.py: command not found
```

What is this Error? and How Can I Fix This Error?

Comment: Procfile: python3 app.py

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik You can edit your comment instead of posting twice. Furthermore the error log says `bash: app.py: command not found`. He does not need a `Procfile` here because he is manually telling heroku to run `python3 app.py`.  
His error is likely that `app.py` does not exist at the root level of his remote git.

Comment: Thanks, @TinNguyen! I never ran something on Heroku without Procfile so that's my mistake. I'll delete my comments.